# Overriding database provider in integration test with WebApplicationFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am following the official MS documentation for integration testing .Net Core (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

I was able to get the first part of the integration test done where I was not overriding the startup class of the application I am testing (i.e. I was using a web application factorythat did not override any services).

I want to override the database setup to use an in-memory database for the integration test. The problem I am running into is that the configuration continues to try and use the sql server for `services.AddHangfire()`.

How do I override only above specific item in my integration test? I only want to override the `AddHangfire` setup and not `services.AddScoped<ISendEmail, SendEmail>().` Any help would be appreciated.

**Test Class with the custom web application factory**

```
 public class HomeControllerShouldCustomFactory : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;
        private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

        public HomeControllerShouldCustomFactory(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;
            _client = factory.CreateClient();
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task IndexRendersCorrectTitle()
        {
            var response = await _client.GetAsync("/Home/Index");

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Assert.Contains("Send Email", responseString);
        }
}
```

**Custom Web Application Factory**

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>: WebApplicationFactory<SendGridExample.Startup>
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                // Create a new service provider.
                var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                    .BuildServiceProvider();

                var inMemory = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseMemoryStorage();
                services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseStorage(inMemory));

                // Build the service provider.
                var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            });
        }
    }
```

**My startup.cs in my application that I am testing**

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; }

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ASP_NetPractice")));
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    services.AddScoped<ISendEmail, SendEmail>();
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHangfireServer();
    app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<ISendEmail>((email) => email.SendReminder(), Cron.Daily);
    app.UseMvc();
```

---

**Update**

I don't see this issue in my other example project where I am using only entity framework. I have a simple application with an application db context which uses SQL server. In my test class, I override it with an in-memory database and everything works. I am at a loss at to why it will work in my example application but not work in my main application. Is this something to do with how HangFire works?

In my test application (example code below), I can delete my sql database, run my test, and the test passes because the application DB context does not go looking for the sql server instance but uses the in-memory database. In my application, the HangFire service keeps trying to use the sql server database (if I delete the database and try to use an in-memory database for the test - it fails because it can't find the instance its trying to connect to). How come there is such a drastic difference in how the two projects work when a similar path is used for both?

I ran through the debugger for my integration test which calls the index method on the home controller above (using the CustomWebApplicationFactory). As I am initializing a test server, it goes through my startup class which calls  below in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ASP_NetPractice")));
```

After that, the Configure method tries to call below statement:

```
app.UseHangfireServer();
```

At this point the test fails as It cannot find the DB. The DB is hosted on Azure so I am trying to replace it with an in-memory server for some of the integration test. Is the approach I am taking incorrect?

---

My example application where its working

**Application DB Context in my example application**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }

        public async  Task<List<Message>> GetMessagesAsync()
        {
            return await Messages
                .OrderBy(message => message.Text)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToListAsync();
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            Messages.AddRange(GetSeedingMessages());
            SaveChanges();
        }

        public static List<Message> GetSeedingMessages()
        {
            return new List<Message>()
            {
                new Message(){ Text = "You're standing on my scarf." },
                new Message(){ Text = "Would you like a jelly baby?" },
                new Message(){ Text = "To the rational mind, nothing is inexplicable; only unexplained." }
            };
        }
    }
```

**Startup.cs in my example application**

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

**CustomWebApplicationFactory - in my unit test project**

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>
     : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                // Create a new service provider.
                var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                    .BuildServiceProvider();

                // Add a database context (ApplicationDbContext) using an in-memory 
                // database for testing.
                services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting");
                    options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
                });

                // Build the service provider.
                var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            });
        }
    }
```

**My unit test in my unit test project**

```
public class UnitTest1 : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;
        private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

        public UnitTest1(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;
            _client = factory.CreateClient();
        }


        [Fact]
        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Test1Async()
        {
            var response = await _client.GetAsync("/");

            //response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Assert.Contains("Home", responseString);
        }
```

[image]

---

**Update 2**

I think I found an alternate to trying to override all my configuration in my integration test class. Since it's a lot more complicated to override HangFire as opposed to an ApplicationDBContext, I came up with below approach:

**Startup.cs**

```
    if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        var inMemory = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseMemoryStorage();
        services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseStorage(inMemory));
    }
    else
    {
        services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration["DBConnection"]));

    }
```

Then in my CustomWebApplicationBuilder, I override the environment type for testing:

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<SendGridExample.Startup>
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.UseEnvironment("Development"); //change to Production for alternate test
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                // Create a new service provider.
                var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                    .BuildServiceProvider();
           });
        }

    }
```

With that approach, I don't need to worry about having to do extra logic to satisfy hangfire's check for an active DB. It works but I am not 100% convinced its the best approach as I'm introducing branching in my production startup class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different scenarios you need to check.

1. Create a job by class `BackgroundJob`
2. Create a job by interface `IBackgroundJobClient`

For the first option, you could not replace the `SqlServerStorage` with `MemoryStorage`.

For `UseSqlServerStorage`, it will reset `JobStorage` by `SqlServerStorage`.

```
        public static IGlobalConfiguration<SqlServerStorage> UseSqlServerStorage(
        [NotNull] this IGlobalConfiguration configuration,
        [NotNull] string nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        if (configuration == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
        if (nameOrConnectionString == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(nameOrConnectionString));

        var storage = new SqlServerStorage(nameOrConnectionString);
        return configuration.UseStorage(storage);
    }
```

`UseStorage`

```
    public static class GlobalConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static IGlobalConfiguration<TStorage> UseStorage<TStorage>(
        [NotNull] this IGlobalConfiguration configuration,
        [NotNull] TStorage storage)
        where TStorage : JobStorage
    {
        if (configuration == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
        if (storage == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(storage));

        return configuration.Use(storage, x => JobStorage.Current = x);
    }
```

Which means, no matter what you set in `CustomWebApplicationFactory`, `UseSqlServerStorage` will reset `BackgroundJob` with `SqlServerStorage`.

For second option, it could replace `IBackgroundJobClient` with `MemoryStorage` by

```
    public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<JobStorage>(x =>
            {
                return GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseMemoryStorage();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

In conclusion, I suggest you register `IBackgroundJobClient` and try the second option to achieve your requirement.

**Update1**

For **DB is not available**, it could not be resolved by configuring the Dependency Injection. This error is caused by calling `services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ASP_NetPractice")));`.

For resolving this error, you need to overriding this code in `Startup.cs`.

Try steps below:

- Change `Startup` to below:

  ```
  public class Startup
  {
  public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
  {
      Configuration = configuration;
  }

  public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
      //Rest Code

      ConfigureHangfire(services);
  }

  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
  {
      //Rest Code
      app.UseHangfireServer();
      RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine("RecurringJob!"), Cron.Minutely);

  }

  protected virtual void ConfigureHangfire(IServiceCollection services)
  {
      services.AddHangfire(config =>
        config.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection"))
      );
  }
  }
  ```
- Create `StartupTest` in test project.

  ```
  public class StartupTest : Startup
  {
  public StartupTest(IConfiguration configuration) :base(configuration)
  {

  }
  protected override void ConfigureHangfire(IServiceCollection services)
  {
      services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseMemoryStorage());
  }
  }
  ```
- `CustomWebApplicationFactory`

  ```
  public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> : WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> where TEntryPoint: class
  {
  protected override IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder()
  {
      return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(null)
          .UseStartup<TEntryPoint>();
  }
  }
  ```
- Test

  ```
  public class HangfireStorageStartupTest : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<StartupTest>>
  {
  private readonly HttpClient _client;
  private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<StartupTest> _factory;

  public HangfireStorageStartupTest(CustomWebApplicationFactory<StartupTest> factory)
  {

      _factory = factory;
      _client = factory.CreateClient();
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: Hi Tao, please see my update for the startup class above. I am initializing my services in startup and also utilizing hangfire server and adding the recurring job in my startup class. Is this the wrong approach to take? My test fails because when the DB is not available, app.UseHangFireServer() tries to access it and fails. Do I need to implement your UseStorage extension class and configure my CustomWebApplicationFactory as per your code above?

Comment: Hi Tao. Thank you for the detailed explanation. That helped a lot. When going through your override method for the HangFire setup, I thought about a simple alternative that works. Is my approach acceptable for this issue?

Comment: @Help123 I think it's ok.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I'll also test your approach out so that I can use it for future. I know that I'll have to eventually override some approaches in my test classes